# Angularjs - Split String issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am temporarily devoid of seeing eyes.. The code below throws up an error

> Error: value.split is not a function

Is threre an angularjs way of splitting a simple string

```
var value = "7,9";

$scope.getTemplate = function(value){

    var values = value.split(",");

    value1 = values[0];
    value2 = values[1];

    $scope.templateid = value1;
    $scope.userid = value2;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you've got a function parameter named `value` which hides the outer variable, `value`. Also, your function definition ends with a `)` rather than a `}`, which is a syntax error, although, I believe that's probably just in issue with how you've posted the code here.

You should also explicitly declare the variables `value1` and `value2` (unless you have actually declared them outside your function).

Try this instead:

```
var value = "7,9";

$scope.getTemplate = function(){
    var values = value.split(",");

    var value1 = values[0];
    var value2 = values[1];

    $scope.templateid = value1;
    $scope.userid = value2;
};
```

Or get rid of the intermediate variables entirely:

```
$scope.getTemplate = function(){
    var values = value.split(",");
    $scope.templateid = values[0];
    $scope.userid = values[1];
};
```

---

**Update** Given your comments it appears the method is actually being called with two parameters, rather than a single string parameter. In this case there's no need to split at all. Try this:

```
$scope.getTemplate = function(value1, value2){
    $scope.templateid = value1;
    $scope.userid = value2;
};
```

Comment: The outer variable is a demonstration of what value looks like. The function receives a string parameter that looks like "x,y" and I need to split it (in function) to get x and y as separate values.. So I need that function parameter.

Comment: @PersistentNewbie Are you sure? Can you do a `console.log(value)` within the function to verify what it actually looks like?

Comment: the function is evoked from ng-click="tbGetTemplate(21,32) .. the console log only returns 21

Comment: Yes, thank you :) There are two methods I am calling,, one with one the other with two parameters,,, there was a bit missing for the second one. Thanks for pointing this out.