# how to get output by splitting a string in angular js

Tags: arrays, angularjs, string, split

I have a string -

"126_VAMSI, SWAP L.  NA_8092069876"

i need to get "VAMSI, SWAP L.  NA" as an output i.e. the words between the underscore, then what should be my approach.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448100/how-to-split-a-string-with-angularjs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639607/angularjs-split-string-issue

Answer (score 2):

> If your question is complete and string only has two underscores and
>   you want the middle text between underscores. Then this is your
>   answer.

```
str.split("_")[1];
```

> If your questioned string is variant pls elaborate